# curl not working after new -o line

Tags: bash, curl

```
getmarkdown()

{

curl -o "/home/adriaancarabao/Nextcloud/test.md"   -X GET http://fuckyeahmarkdown.com/go/?u=$1\&read=1\&md=1

}
```

non-functional after I put `curl -o "/home/adriaancarabao/Nextcloud/test.md"` infront

I found something about double-quote and reference to $1 but I don't grasp that.

Comment: by "non-functional" you mean destination file is still empty ?

Comment: what is the value of `$1` ? no funny char ?

Comment: yes, i mean it is empty

Comment: strange `-o` (lower case o) will output only http dialog for me, I used `-O` (upper case) to write actual document.

Comment: It works now, only with -o after removing the " is it possible to change the output name based on the url input.